# doubly linked list with for loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I just learned about pointers in c++, and my instructor told to create a doubly linked list with a for loop. However, the only example I was given was

```
    Node *n1 = new Node(1);
    Node *n2 = new Node(2);
    Node *n3 = new Node(3);
    Node *n4 = new Node(4);
    Node *n5 = new Node(5);
    DL_List mylist;
    if (mylist.empty())
        mylist.insert(n1, mylist.head);
    mylist.insert(n2, n1);
    mylist.insert(n3, n2);
    mylist.insert(n4, n3);
    mylist.insert(n5, n4);
    mylist.display();
```

I have no idea how to set a for loop for this because I don't know how to name them in the loop, or how I would connect them.

Comment: You might want to go to your instructor.

Comment: Are you asking how to call `insert()` in a loop? You would store the `Node*` pointers in an array, and then loop through the array

Comment: One of the beauties of a loop is [it is scoped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). You can use the same name over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what mylist.insert(a, b) does? Insert node a into to position b? Normally, to do what you said, we use the code as below:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_nodes_you_want_to_insert; ++i) {
    Node *n = new Node(i);
    mylist.insert(n);
}
```

Comment: void insert(Node *newnode, Node *pred);

It's suppose to be doubly linked.

Comment: Okay, see the user4581301's answer. He/she makes it very clear.

Answer (score 0):

The names, identifiers, mean nothing. They are simply place holders. We use nice names because it makes things easier for the human brain to understand what the variable is for. The computer does not care. It chucks the name as soon as possible and replaces it with an address, an offset from an address or a hardware register.

You cannot use the same identifier within the same scope, but the scope of a loop ends with the end of the loop and then starts over again recreating any identifiers if the loop requires another iteration.

What goes in the loop? Obviously we need to create a `Node` and insert the node, but we also need to keep track of where to insert the next node. This leads to a semi-bug in the teacher-provided example:

```
DL_List mylist;
if (mylist.empty()) // list better not be constructed with pre-existing nodes
    mylist.insert(n1, mylist.head); // because this doesn't happen if it isn't empty
mylist.insert(n2, n1); // and where is n1, Hmmm? We might not have added it.
```

`n1` wouldn't be in the list and if it's not in the list, then linking `n2` to `n1` for the list isn't such a good idea.

My pitch has slightly different behaviour, but at least it isn't broken behaviour. I suggest always inserting the first node at the beginning of the list., If there happens to be stuff already in the list, so be it. It gets pushed toward the end of the list.

In this case you need one extra place-holder to keep track of where to insert, and the value of this placeholder needs to remain intact between iterations of the loop. To allow it to persist we define it outside the loop.

```
Node * where_to_insert = mylist.head;
for (int count = 1; cows.not_home(); count++)
{
    Node * n = new Node(count);
    mylist.insert(n, where_to_insert);
    where_to_insert = n;
}
```

The above will loop and add nodes until the cows come home. Hopefully they will come home before count overflows, but this eventuality can be avoided by using a more relevant terminating condition for the loop.